# How do I reroll the dice in Yahtzee

Tags: java

I am I very beginner programmer and I am stuck on how I can reroll the dice in my program. The project that I am working on is Yahtzee. In Yahtzee, you roll 5 dice and you can choose what dice to reroll ('r') and what dice to keep ('k'). In all, I am trying to roll 2 times. 
package yahtzee1;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Yahtzee1 {
    /**
     * Allows the get information from the user like to keep or reroll
     * @param prompt
     * @return 
     */
     public static char getcharFromUser(String prompt) { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(prompt);
        char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
        return c;
     }

    /**
     * generate 5 random numbers from 1 to 6, inclusive
     * @param dice array to store the numbers
     */
    public static void roll(int[] dice) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            dice[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * generate 5 random numbers from 1 to 6, inclusive
     *
     * @param dice array to store the numbers
     */
    public static void printDice(int[] dice) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print(dice[i]);
        }
    }

   /**
    * After the 5 dice are "rolled" user picks which dice to re-roll or keep
    * @param dice
    * @param option 
    */
    public static void reRoll(int[] dice, String option) {

        //help here
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param dice 
     */
    public static void playRound(int [] dice){
       for (int i = 0; i < 2;i++){
            reRoll(dice, option);

            roll(dice);

            printDice(dice);
        }
    }
    /**
     * play Yahtzee
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] dice = new int[6];
        playRound(dice);
    }


}
```

the section in my code where I need help is in the method reRoll.

Comment: I am not quite sure I iunderrstand your progam logic. In method `playRound(...)`, you call `reRoll(...)` before you call `roll(...)`. Are you sure that this is correct?

Comment: Please explain your code, guide us through your program. Then it will be far easier for us to find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static void reRoll(int[] dice, String option) {
    //Change the split parameter to whatever you need the delimiter to be
    for(String numString: option.split(" ")){ 
        int die = Integer.parseInt(numString);
        dice[die-1] = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    }

}

public static void playRound(int [] dice){

    roll(dice);

    printDice(dice);

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   for (int i = 0; i < 2;i++){

       System.out.print("Enter dice to reroll: ");

       String option = sc.nextLine();

        reRoll(dice, option);

        printDice(dice);
    }

   sc.close();
}
```